# sas libname in unix format

Tags: sas

I'm trying to change the following hypothetical libname reference to something else to make it point to a different share drive.

```
libname mylibref '/u/mystuff/sastuff/work';
```

This references to share drive `k:\`.

And I want to change it to point to share drive `m:\`.

How should I change `/u/mystuff/sastuff/work` to do that? I'm on a Windows machine and I don't know why this SAS libname is in Unix format. I took over some projects that are written in SAS and wasn't really familiar with this particular reference format...

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Unix libname, chances are the code is designed to be remote-submitted to a Unix SAS server.

e.g.

```
/* Local code - processed on PC */
libname local 'c:\temp' ;
data local.test ;
  do i = 1 to 100 ; 
    output ;
  end ;
run ;

rsubmit ;
  /* Remote code - processed on server */
  libname unix '/u/user/stuff' ;
  data unix.test ;
    do i = 1 to 100 ; 
      output ;
    end ;
  run ;
endrsubmit ;
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS can be overly helpful with it's syntax and try's to make life easier for users, but sometimes it can be confusing.  This is a good example.

The forward slashes in your current libname statement are interpreted as a path on the **current default Windows drive** for your SAS session, which apparently in your case is **drive K** and would be equivalent to:

```
libname mylibref 'K:\u\mystuff\sastuff\work';
```

So, to change the libref to your **M drive** just submit a new libname statement:

```
libname mylibref 'M:\u\mystuff\sastuff\work';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth remembering that forward slashes CAN be used on the windows, so something like the following should execute without errors:

```
libname mylibref 'M:/u/mystuff/sastuff/work';
```

The reverse (backslashes\on\unix) would NOT work!

Not sure if this would really work in your case though, unless you have a mount point from your M drive to unix..